# PHP get thumbnail from online video

Tags: php

Is there a way to generate a thumbnail image from mp4 files on my server?

Do i have to read the complete file for a thumbnail, or is there a way to just get the video information , seek to the frame at middle of the video and take that frame as a thumbnail?

Any Help or example is highly appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Documentation is great and you probably want:

```
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(42));
$frame->save('image.jpg');
```